# XPath select nodes by nesting (most nested nodes minus one)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, nodes, treenode

This is the xml given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root>
    <WorkItem>
        <Id>716</Id>
        <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
        <TreeLevel>0</TreeLevel>
        <Children>
            <WorkItem>
                <Id>717</Id>
                <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
                <TreeLevel>1</TreeLevel>
                <Children>
                    <WorkItem>
                        <Id>719</Id>
                        <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
                        <TreeLevel>2</TreeLevel>
                        <Children>
                            <WorkItem>
                                <Id>721</Id>
                                <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                                <TreeLevel>3</TreeLevel>
                                <Children />
                            </WorkItem>
                        </Children>
                    </WorkItem>
                    <WorkItem>
                        <Id>720</Id>
                        <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
                        <TreeLevel>2</TreeLevel>
                        <Children>
                            <WorkItem>
                                <Id>724</Id>
                                <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                                <TreeLevel>3</TreeLevel>
                                <Children />
                            </WorkItem>
                        </Children>
                    </WorkItem>
                    <WorkItem>
                        <Id>723</Id>
                        <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                        <TreeLevel>2</TreeLevel>
                        <Children>
                            <WorkItem>
                                <Id>744</Id>
                                <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                                <TreeLevel>3</TreeLevel>
                                <Children>
                                    <WorkItem>
                                        <Id>747</Id>
                                        <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                                        <TreeLevel>4</TreeLevel>
                                        <Children />
                                    </WorkItem>
                                </Children>
                            </WorkItem>
                        </Children>
                    </WorkItem>
                    <WorkItem>
                        <Id>748</Id>
                        <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                        <TreeLevel>2</TreeLevel>
                        <Children />
                    </WorkItem>
                    <WorkItem>
                        <Id>752</Id>
                        <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
                        <TreeLevel>2</TreeLevel>
                        <Children>
                            <WorkItem>
                                <Id>753</Id>
                                <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
                                <TreeLevel>3</TreeLevel>
                                <Children />
                            </WorkItem>
                        </Children>
                    </WorkItem>
                </Children>
            </WorkItem>
            <WorkItem>
                <Id>718</Id>
                <WorkItemType>Task</WorkItemType>
                <TreeLevel>1</TreeLevel>
                <Children />
            </WorkItem>
        </Children>
    </WorkItem>
</Root>
```

Simplified the xml is like this

```
716 (PBI) Root
  - 717 (PBI)
    - 719 (PBI)
      - 721 (Task)
    - 720 (PBI)
      - 724 (Task)
    - 723 (Task)
      - 744 (Task)
        - 747 (Task)
    - 748 (Task)
    - 752 (PBI)
      - 753 (PBI)
  - 718 (Task)
```

I would like to retrieve all second inner nodes of the WorkItemType "Product Backlog Item".
I could also say I want to have "Product Backlog Items" which have child elements with type "Product Backlog Item" but no child-child elements of "Product Backlog Item".

In the given example this would be

I tried to receive it with this xpath command (I use System.Xml.XmlDocument in C#):

```
//WorkItem[WorkItemType[text()='Product Backlog Item'] and ./Children/WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item'] and not(./Children//WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item']/Children/WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item'])]
```

for better readability

```
//WorkItem[WorkItemType[text()='Product Backlog Item'] 
and ./Children/WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item'] 
and not(./Children//WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item']/Children/WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item'])]
```

With this XPath expression I get the Items with ID 716, 717 and 752.

But I want only the item **752.**

Comment: Why aren't u using `LINQ TO XML` for this?

Comment: @Sybren thank you for your comment. I use xpath because I store the xpath expression in a configuration file. This file needs to be extended in the future. To how I understand `LINQ TO XML` it's not possible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "second inner nodes"?

Comment: @YacoubMassad thanks for the comment. I tried to describe it. If you check the simplified xml structure I would like to select 752. This is the second inner most node of type PBI (Product Backlog Item).

Comment: I think I found a solution for my problem with this query: //WorkItem[WorkItemType[text()='Product Backlog Item'] and Children/WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() = 'Product Backlog Item'] and not(Children/WorkItem/WorkItemType[text() != 'Product Backlog Item'])]

Answer (score 0):

We do not know exactly how much variation there is in the structure of your XML documents, but try to look at it from an entirely different perspective.

Start with the innermost `WorkItem` that has an element `WorkItemType = 'Product Backlog Item'` but no child `WorkItem` elements whatsoever. Then, work your way backwards using the `parent::` axis.

The full XPath expression would look like

```
//WorkItem[WorkItemType = 'Product Backlog Item' and not(Children/WorkItem)]/parent::Children/parent::WorkItem
```

and the only result would be

```
<WorkItem>
    <Id>752</Id>
    <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
    <TreeLevel>2</TreeLevel>
    <Children>
        <WorkItem>
            <Id>753</Id>
            <WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</WorkItemType>
            <TreeLevel>3</TreeLevel>
            <Children/>
        </WorkItem>
    </Children>
</WorkItem>
```

---

Note that the expression above requires that the inner `WorkItem` does not contain any other `WorkItem` element - which is not exactly what you have asked. If I were to follow your description very closely, this would lead me to

```
//WorkItem[WorkItemType = 'Product Backlog Item' and not(Children/WorkItem[WorkItemType = 'Product Backlog Item'])]/parent::Children/parent::WorkItem
```

which would also include the `WorkItem` with ID `717`.